# Create a product pack with Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2.0

Tags: e-commerce, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am looking for a way to create product packs with Joomla 2.5 and Virtuemart 2.0.

By a product pack, i mean a product which would be composed of several products.
For example, I would have :

- product A
- product B
- product C
- Pack 1 (A + B, with discount)
- Pack 2 (A + B + C, with discount)

Then, buying a pack would add all sub-products to cart, or destock the amount of each subproduct.

For now, I haven't managed to find a way to do this, but I was told this is possible.

Can someone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find the extension "Product Builder" useful for what you want to do with the bundled products. http://breakdesigns.net/virtuemart-product-builder

Also, if you are open to other carts, you will find that you can do some very nice product-as-an-option configuration in HikaShop.

Answer (score 0):

Check "Product Bundles" as well

> Prompt your users to buy a set of products at a discounted price
>   instead of a single one

http://breakdesigns.net/extensions/product-bundles

Comment: A better way to answer would be to show code or explain rather than link. The link might be dead at some point.

Comment: Also an answer to a question asked almost 2 years ago is not of much help ;)

Comment: Its not just some lines of code that could be submited here. It's a new functionality that needs 2 different plugins to do that. Also maybe the question is old but it is very current and still unsanswered for many users

Answer (score 0):

Its not just some lines of code that could be submited here. It's a new functionality that needs 2 different plugins to do that.
Also maybe the question is old but it is very current and still interesting for many users

Answer (score 0):

Catproduct is another option: http://sm-planet.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=2:catproduct&catid=8&Itemid=110